# how can I create at least docker container with the same open port?

Tags: docker

Can I have at least two domains on a server with the same open ports so that we have two separate and different containers?
Originally I want to enable two domains on one IP and have a separate container for each domain. Suppose if we enable hundreds of domains in a container with the help of virtual hosts, we need another container for the other domains on the same IP. How do I enable multiple separate containers with the same 80 and 443 ports?

Comment: One port on an address can only be used by at most one application at one point in time. Does this answer your question?

Comment: It's possible, but you'd need 2 network interfaces each with their own ip address. This is quite easy to arrange in a public cloud such as AWS. With only one network interface, what you really need is a kubernetes ingress controller using layer-7 routing. But, given the question you asked I'm guessing that this would require a lot of studying.

Comment: Building on top of @software engineer comment, you could use a simple nginx (or any other proxy) container to route the requests to each of your containers (the ones you want  running on the same port) based on layer 4/7 rules (i.e. if path is /app1 route to the port of the first container and if it's /app2 route to the different port used by the second container. Would that be possibly helpful in your situation?

Comment: Originally
  I want to enable two domains on one IP and have a separate container for each domain.
Suppose if we enable hundreds of domains in a container with the help of virtual hosts, we need another container for the other domains on the same IP.
How do I enable multiple separate containers with the same 80 and 443 ports?